KonvaJS Canvas Export size and performance
I am trying to export the konvaJs stage as base64 using stage.toDataURL().
I would like to export the stage with size 36 by 48 inch which is 10800 by 14400 resolution.
I am using pixelRatio to generate the exported output with this desired resolution.
It is a huge resolution. I have all the konvaJS logic on client side. Exporting such a huge resolution is impacting the performance as the final output is above 50MB.
I tried setting quality to 0.5 but still the size of final output is huge.
Is there any better solution that I could use.
I appreciate any help with this please.

I assume your design requires that huge canvas size and I assume the reason for your huge canvas export size is that the image will be used for high-res print. If yes, then the short answer is: No, a huge-sized canvas export will create a huge sized file. BTW, 50mb is not that huge for an image file now-a-day ;-)

@markE Thank you for the feedback. Yes you are correct, The exported image will be used for high res printing. I am comparing this implementation with editors like shutterstock, which are exporting the same output with same resolution of 12mb. They might be doing server side image sacling not sure what. 50MB matters a lot to me as my app is customer facing and with a slow network speed, it could take a while to upload 50MB causing poor user experience. I am looking for better solution than I have in place or any route that I should follow if I handle this on server side.

Yep. Since you have a server, offer this service to your user. 1. The user creates the image in their browser (in KonvaJS, I presume). 2. Your app serializes & uploads the KonvaJS design to your server (this should be a small files size since no actual pixels are created during export). 3. Your server uses the upload to create the huge canvas/huge file (probably using NodeJS). 4. Your server "parks" the huge image file so that the eventual end consumer (print company, etc) can use their broad-band network connection to download the huge file at the desired resolution.
